# How to distinguish between two arraylists while retuning result in a ResponseEntity

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, arraylist

I have a situation where i have to return two  empty lists in case a certain condition satisfies , but in the return result , i have to distinguish between these two and show the output based on them, i want to find a way to distinguish between them , i am posting the code i have written ,

```
public List<InvoiceHeaderEntity> fetchInvoiceHeaderDetails(List<SearchCriteria> params) {
    List<InvoiceHeaderEntity> invoiceHeaderListBigList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    CriteriaQuery<InvoiceHeaderEntity> query = getInvoiceListHeaderEntityCriteriaQuery(params);
    List<InvoiceHeaderEntity> invoiceHeaderList = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    int count = invoiceHeaderList.size(); //getting the count here from DB
    if(count>=2000) {
    entityManager.close();
    return invoiceHeaderListBigList; returning empty list if count is greater than 2000
    }else if(count<=2000) {
        return invoiceHeaderList;
    }
    return Collections.emptyList(); // if nothing is founf in DB return empty list
```

converting the output into the DTO

```
@Override
public List<InvoiceHeaderDto> listOfInvoiceHeader(InvoiceSearchDto invoiceSearchDto){
    logger.info("Entering into listOfInvoiceHeader");
    List<InvoiceHeaderEntity> invoiceHeaderEntityList = invoiceCustomRepository.fetchInvoiceHeaderDetails(getParam(invoiceSearchDto));
    logger.info("Exiting into listOfInvoiceHeader");
    return invoiceHeaderEntityList.stream()
            .map(invoiceHeaderEntity->objectMapper.convertValue(invoiceHeaderEntity, InvoiceHeaderDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

//In the controller class

```
@Override
@GetMapping(path="/search-invoice-header")
public ResponseEntity<List<InvoiceHeaderDto>> getListOfInvoiceHeader(InvoiceSearchDto invoiceSearchDto){
    logger.info("Entering into getListOfInvoiceHeader");
    List<InvoiceHeaderDto> responseListForHeader = invoiceHeaderService.listOfInvoiceHeader(invoiceSearchDto);
    if(responseListForHeader.size()>=2000) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseListForHeader,HttpStatus.OK);
    }else if(responseListForHeader.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseListForHeader,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(invoiceHeaderService.listOfInvoiceHeader(invoiceSearchDto), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

// Trying to show the output in the react code where i have 3 cases

1. Less than 2000 will show the result
2. Greater than 2000 will show empty screen
3. By default empty list will come when nothing is found in DB

I am facing problem distinguishing the case when i will get result greater than 2000 results and will get 0 results

Below is the code

```
Promise.all([
  invoiceSearchService.searchInvoiceInquiry(reqParamObj),
  invoiceSearchService.searchInvoiceInquiryDetails(reqParamObj),
])
  .then((response) => {
    setData(response[0].data); 
    setDetailData(response[1].data);
    returnDataHeader = response[0].data.length;
    returnDataDetail = response[1].data.length;
    if(returnDataHeader!=0 && returnDataDetail!=0){
    setResultPanelVisibility(true); 
    setHeaderPanelDataExceed(false);
    setDetailPanelDataExceed(false);
    } else{
    setResultPanelVisibility(true); 
    setHeaderPanelDataExceed(true);
    setDetailPanelDataExceed(true);
    } 
    context.current.setSprinnerVisibility(false);
  })
  .catch((e)=>{
    setData([]);
    context.current.setSprinnerVisibility(false);
    if(
      e!==undefined &&
      e.response !== undefined &&
      e.response.data !==undefined
    ){
      if(e.response.data.status == 404){
        GrowlUtil.showWarningMessage(
          growl,
          ToasterMessageUtil.FAILED_TO_FETCH_DETAILS
        );
      }else{
        GrowlUtil.showErrorMessage(
          growl,
          ToasterMessageUtil.FAILED_TO_FETCH_DETAILS
        );
      }
    }
  })
};
```

Is there any way  either in Java or react end i can fulfill my requirement. I have also tried to return HttpStatus code but  other than 200 it is going to exception block every time.

```
List<InvoiceHeaderDto> responseListForHeader = invoiceHeaderService.listOfInvoiceHeader(invoiceSearchDto);
    if(responseListForHeader.size()>=2000) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseListForHeader,HttpStatus.BANDWIDTH_LIMIT_EXCEEDED);
    }else if(responseListForHeader.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseListForHeader,HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }//this way , but it failed also
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit? You say in React you have 3 cases, but I see 2... In Spring you can always return an array or a list, where the first element is your list of elements and the second element is whatever you like...

Answer (score 0):

You can throw exception.

```java
public List<InvoiceHeaderEntity> fetchInvoiceHeaderDetails(List<SearchCriteria> params) {
    // ...
    if(count>=2000) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Too many results");
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you are not able to modify `fetchInvoiceHeaderDetails`, you can identify it by concrete class of result type.
(However this is just workaround and not a good solution.)

```java
    public List<InvoiceHeaderDto> listOfInvoiceHeader(InvoiceSearchDto invoiceSearchDto){
        logger.info("Entering into listOfInvoiceHeader");
        List<InvoiceHeaderEntity> invoiceHeaderEntityList = invoiceCustomRepository.fetchInvoiceHeaderDetails(getParam(invoiceSearchDto));
        if(invoiceHeaderEntityList.isEmpty() && invoiceHeaderEntityList instanceof ArrayList) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Too many results");
        }
        // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if i throw exception how i will show some output in the screen in react, like i said too many result is also a case in my case , in the case of too many result i will show a dropdown to download data as excel but in case of blank list i will show blank screen